# Express JS - Using server side JS check if app is running on localhost

Tags: javascript, node.js, server-side

I am needing to check if my node js app using ExpressJS is running on my localhost (Development env.) and not on the live server and execute certain code if so. This has to be done server side. Any ideas how to check this?

Comment: You'll probably get answers telling you to look at [`req.hostname`](http://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#req.hostname). Don't. It's derived from the `Host` header, which is trivially spoofed.

Comment: One option is to check the path variable `__dirname`. Check to see if it matches the server path. You can also add a file to the server directory that is not in your localhost directory. If it exists (or doesn't) you can check for that.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Pass [process.env](https://nodejs.org/api/process.html#process_process_env) variable to your node.js instance like this (for example)

```
node -e 'process.env.NODE_ENV = "development"'
```

and then just use

```
if(process.env.NODE_ENV === 'development') {
    ...
}
```

Comment: Yeah. I think the only way to do this without relying on the `Host` header (which is not reliable) is to explicitly tell `app.listen` to bind to only the local address (e.g., `192.0.0.1` in IPv4). Which means you'll need a way to tell your app you want to do that, which means you may as well just...use that to know how it's running.